# How to design the artificial intelligence of a fighting game (Street Fighter or Soul Calibur)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

There are many papers about ranged combat artificial intelligences, like Killzones's ([see this paper](http://www.cgf-ai.com/docs/straatman_remco_killzone_ai.pdf)), or Halo. But I've not been able to find much about a fighting IA except for this [work](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.592&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which uses neural networs to learn how to fight, which is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Occidental AI in games is heavily focused on FPS, it seems! Does anyone know which techniques are used to implement a decent fighting AI? Hierarchical Finite State Machines? Decision Trees? They could end up being pretty predictable.

Comment: I don't know enough on the subject to give a decent answer, but try throwing in a bit of random error to give it a non-predictable "human" feel as weel. Intelligence makes mistakes too, and simple mutation affords a large amount of diversity.

Comment: Sure. If I finally use a decision tree, I'll add some randomness to it. Something like, on the 'enemy attacks' -> 'blocking 0.8; evading 0.2' sense, so it's not alway the same response.

Comment: Street Fighter Type games application of A.I. is not very heavy. The objective of the game is to deal damage to opponent and prevent damage to your avatar to win the game. Using RNG you can make the behavior more realistic if its able to block or do combinations of attack a percentage of the time depending on the level of difficulty. Higher difficulty means higher chances that the A.I. opponent will block your avatar's attack or successfully do combinations of attack to your avatar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our research labs, we are using AI planning technology for games. AI Planning is used by NASA to build semi-autonomous robots. Planning can produce less predictable behavior than state machines, but planning is a highly complex problem, that is, solving planning problems has a huge computational complexity.

AI Planning is an old but interesting field. Particularly for gaming only recently people have started using planning to run their engines. The expressiveness is still limited in the current implementations, but in theory the expressiveness is limited "only by our imagination".

Russel and Norvig have devoted 4 chapters on AI Planning in their book on Artificial Intelligence. Other related terms you might be interested in are: Markov Decision Processes, Bayesian Networks. These topics are also provided sufficient exposure in this book.

If you are looking for some ready-made engine to easily start using, I guess using AI Planning would be a gross overkill. I don't know of any AI Planning engine for games but we are developing one. If you are interested in the long term, we can talk separately about it.

Comment: Right, something like that was used in Fallout3, as far as I know. But AI Planning doesn't seem to be the answer here, as a fighter does not really 'plan' anything, right? There's no goal like 'uppercut' or 'hit enemy'... is there? It seems something more reactive, combined with a certain fighting style depending on the character (big guys are slow, they tend to block instead of evade and those things...). Nevertheless, I'll have a deeper look at AI planning.

Comment: It's often called "Goal-Oriented Action Planning" (GOAP) AI, popularized by the game, "F.E.A.R.", by Monolith.

Comment: @Notnasiul Actually the fighter or any non-playing character may be controlled by a planner, whose plan is to maximize the player experience. Sometimes they way to do this by trying to stick to a certain curve over time of the motivation of the player. Such a curve is also the hallmark of Spielberg movies.

Comment: @Pup GOAP is the nomenclature adopted by FEAR, and Jeff Orkins, who is working in this field, but actually the area is much larger. For example, check http://scholar.google.com.sg/scholar?q=ai+planning+games

Comment: F.E.A.R.'s bots are not much smarter than toads in NES Super Mario.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to know already the techniques for planning and executing. Another thing that you need to do is predict the opponent's next move and maximize the expected reward of your response. I wrote a blog article about this: http://www.masterbaboon.com/2009/05/my-ai-reads-your-mind-and-kicks-your-ass-part-2/ and http://www.masterbaboon.com/2009/09/my-ai-reads-your-mind-extensions-part-3/ . The game I consider is *very* simple, but I think the main ideas from Bayesian decision theory might be useful for your project.

Comment: Thank you a lot! And nice blog, I'm following it now ;) (I like that Pacman capture the flag game!)

Comment: Thank you! By the way, we plan to have an open-source variant of the Pacman game by next February.

Answer (score 2):

I have reverse engineered the routines related to the AI subsystem within the Street Figher II series of games.  It does not incorporate any of the techniques mentioned above.  It is entirely reactive and involves no planning, learning or goals.  Interestingly, there is no "technique weight" system that you mention, either. They don't use global weights for decisions to decide the frequency of attack versus block, for example.  When taking apart the routines related to how "difficulty" is made to seem to increase, I did expect to find something like that.  Alas, it relates to a number of smaller decisions that could potentially affect those ratios in an emergent way.

Answer (score 1):

Another route to consider is the so called `Ghost AI` as described [here](http://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~vishnu/gameProg/papers/wpj_vishnu07.pdf) & [here](http://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~vishnu/gameProg/papers/CGAT_Real%20Time%20Imitaion%20Based%20Learning.pdf). As the name suggests you basically extract rules from actual game play, first paper does it offline and the second extends the methodology for online real time learning.

Check out also the guy's [webpage](http://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~vishnu/), there are a number of other papers on fighting games that are interesting.

Comment: That Ghost AI is pretty interesting, but not what I was looking for, though. I wanted, precisely, a manner of giving the AI its own 'personalty'. I've been coding this weekend and the combination of a FSM with some randomness based on 'technique weights' (offensive, defensive, blocker/avoider...) seems to be appropriate. And that guy's webpage is a design crime ;)

Comment: The whole purpose of the Ghost AI was to have an opponent with it's own personality even if it got trained by imitating another player. Your approach sounds interesting, not sure how much tweaking it needs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ice.ci.ritsumei.ac.jp/~ftgaic/index-R.html

its old but here are some examples

Comment: [Link-only examples are discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice). Please add the relevant information to your answer.

Comment: It's best to include the relevant parts from links in your answer.  This prevents the answer from becoming not useful in the future if that link to the other information dies.

Comment: sorry its from a contest hosted by a university where people entered their AI code and had their bots fight each other. Written in Javascript. I found it useful, I finally decided to write the AI in my game using a stacked state machine method.